# How to place qed symbol at the end of an equation using eqnarray* enviroment

Tags: math-mode, positioning, amsmath, proof-package

I am having trouble getting the qed symbol at the end of my equation, the symbol ends up on the next line. I have tried using the \qedhere command, but that doesn't work in the eqnarray* environment. How do I get around that issue?

```
\begin{proof}
The DM's expected payoff with threshold $t$ and discount factor $\delta $ is%

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty }\left( \delta F\left( t\right) ^{n}\right) ^{i}\left(
1-F\left( t\right) ^{n}\right) E\left[ \theta |\theta >t\right] \\
&=&\frac{1-F\left( t\right) ^{n}}{1-\delta F\left( t\right) ^{n}}E\left[
\theta |\theta >t\right]
\end{eqnarray*}%
while each expert's expected payoff is%
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty }\left( \delta F\left( t\right) ^{n}\right) ^{i}\left(
1-F\left( t\right) \right) A\left( t\right) E\left[ \theta |\theta >t\right]
\\
&=&\frac{\left( 1-F\left( t\right) \right) A\left( t\right) E\left[ \theta
|\theta >t\right] }{1-\delta F\left( t\right) ^{n}}\text{.}
\end{eqnarray*}%
Eliminating common terms the result then follows since%
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1-F\left( t\right) ^{n}}{1-F\left( t\right) }=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}F\left(
t\right) ^{i}=n\text{ }A\left( t\right)\text{.}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{proof}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) do yourself a favour: forget you ever heard of `eqnarray`, it is filled with bad decisions. Use the `amsmath` envs. (3) Next time please post a fully compilable example where those trying to help does not have to add stuff in order to test your code.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

First and most important: ***never*** use `eqnarray` for any reason whatsoever.

Second: never leave a blank line before a display.

Third: LaTeX doesn't force anybody to use `\left` and `\right` in front of each parenthesis or bracket; if your editor does it automatically, disable the feature.

Fourth: from the chosen breaks, I guess you're writing in a two column format; for this case, `multline` is the environment to choose.

Fifth: `amsthm` provides `\qedhere` just for this case. It works in every `amsmath` alignment and in `equation`, but not with `eqnarray`. Since you're not going to use `eqnarray` any more…

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The DM's expected payoff with threshold $t$ and discount factor $\delta $ is
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\delta F(t)^{n})^{i}(1-F(t)^{n}) E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\\
=\frac{1-F(t)^{n}}{1-\delta F(t)^{n}}E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\end{multline*}
while each expert's expected payoff is
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\delta F(t)^{n})^{i}(1-F(t))A(t)E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\\
=\frac{(1-F(t))A(t)E[\theta\mid\theta>t]}{1-\delta F(t)^{n}}.
\end{multline*}
Eliminating common terms the result then follows since
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1-F(t)^{n}}{1-F(t)}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}F(t)^{i}=nA(t).
\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Note also `\mid` instead of `|` for getting the proper spacing.

[image]

An alternative to `multiline` is `align`, but I would prefer the above solution.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The DM's expected payoff with threshold $t$ and discount factor $\delta $ is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\delta F(t)^{n})^{i}(1-F(t)^{n}) E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\\
&\quad=\frac{1-F(t)^{n}}{1-\delta F(t)^{n}}E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\end{align*}
while each expert's expected payoff is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\delta F(t)^{n})^{i}(1-F(t))A(t)E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\\
&\quad=\frac{(1-F(t))A(t)E[\theta\mid\theta>t]}{1-\delta F(t)^{n}}.
\end{align*}
Eliminating common terms the result then follows since
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1-F(t)^{n}}{1-F(t)}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}F(t)^{i}=nA(t).
\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are a couple of suggestions about how to modify the appearance.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\proof{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\clubsuit$}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The DM's expected payoff with threshold $t$ and discount factor $\delta $ is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\delta F(t)^{n})^{i}(1-F(t)^{n}) E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\\
&\quad=\frac{1-F(t)^{n}}{1-\delta F(t)^{n}}E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\end{align*}
while each expert's expected payoff is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(\delta F(t)^{n})^{i}(1-F(t))A(t)E[\theta \mid \theta>t]
\\
&\quad=\frac{(1-F(t))A(t)E[\theta\mid\theta>t]}{1-\delta F(t)^{n}}.
\end{align*}
Eliminating common terms the result then follows since%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1-F(t)^{n}}{1-F(t)}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}F(t)^{i}=nA(t).
\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Use whatever you like instead of `$\clubsuit$`.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, how can I center my equations though? When I run it, the first line of the equation is flushleft and the second is flushright.

Comment: @JoshEubanks That's how `multline` is supposed to do and it's very common practice for this type of split equations. I added an alternative.

Comment: you failed to explicitly mention "never leave a blank line between text and a following display".

Comment: @barbarabeeton Now it's mentioned. ;-)

Comment: +1. Nice touch to replace all instances of `|` with `\mid`. A further possible improvement: provide `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}` in the preamble and replace the four instances of math-mode `E` with `\E` -- better to write the "expectation operator" letter in the upright font shape to have TeX insert a thinspace ahead of each `\E`.

Comment: I prefer the align version (usually combined with MoveEqLeft from mathtools), I feel it gives a more consistent look to the equations than multline

Comment: @egreg Using eqnarray* gave me a shaded in black square at the end and I fixed that. It also had proof as bold without italics or a period at the end. How do I fix that? I used \renewcommand{\proofname}{\textbf{Proof}} and that didn't fix it.

Comment: @JoshEubanks Do `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{<whatever>}`, where `<whatever>` stands for the code you used for the tombstone. For the proof name in boldface, I'll add the trick.

Comment: @egreg How do I make all the equations flushleft? It isn't for this one, it is for a different equation

Comment: @JoshEubanks Check the `flalign` environment